# How to link a shapefile with points to a shapefile with lines?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, coordinate-system, line

I have a shapefile with points (nodes) and a shapefile with lines (pipeline) which I have extracted from a water distribution network. I have been able to transform the points into the right projection and the layer looks good, but the lines I dont know how to project or illustrate. In the attribute table there is the name of the start node and end node. Can I link the shapefile with lines to the points?

Comment: Its in ArcGIS by the way

Comment: Something for the future - You can edit your question to reference ArcGIS rather than needing a comment.

Comment: If you do a Join, you can link the line to its start or end point but not both (assuming the point names are the same as the start and end node names in the table). I'm not sure what issue you have with projecting or 'illustrating' the lines - if you add the shapefile the lines and points should line up if you do the same transformations on both. We might be able to provide better direction if you can edit your question to explain more what you're trying to do (what does this 'link' accomplish?).

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables together.  Right Click on the point shapefile and join it with the line shapefile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do Spatial Adjustment (Edge Snap/Edge match) to link your points and polyline. I have been doing this as well as I'm working with water utilities. Just make sure you are creating a link for the right point to the right node in the polyline. A few links will do.

[image]